# How to make the Wordpress Editor not accept HTML?

Tags: php, wordpress

So basically, I am using the Wordpress editor on my site and I do not want my users posting ANY HTML in it at all since it can cause some problems.

My Wordpress Editor is currently like this:

```
<?php wp_editor( get_the_content() , 'post_content'); ?>
```

In simple terms, I would basically like it to just look like a simple HTML `textarea`, and strip all HTML tags (like what the PHP function `strip_tags` does. Although, I cannot get this PHP functionality working with a simple textarea... Not to sure why, just a coding problem with my theme.

So yes, is something like this possible?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about WordPress and has been asked and answered here already: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121114/how-to-make-the-wordpress-editor-not-accept-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think you can use `array_map` to strip tags of all elements of array you are saving in database like so ..**

**`$save_to_db = array_map('strip_tags', $save_to_db);`**

Comment: Hmmm, this may be very useful. Will try it out and report back.

Answer (score 1):

Since `get_the_content()` returns a string of the entered content, it would simply be your user's input, unfiltered, for example: `"This is an <em>unfiltered</em> string with <strong>potential HTML included!</strong>"`

If you're initializing the editor, could you not simply call `strip_tags` on said input during initialization?

```
<?php wp_editor( strip_tags(get_the_content()), 'post_content'); ?>
```

The final text would be as it would be if it were ran through `strip_tags`: `"This is an unfiltered string with potential HTML included!"`

Comment: Unfortunately, that only loads the content from the database without any HTML. They are still able to type in HTML to the editor and have it saved to the database. Therefore, their HTML will be saved to the database and displayed on the site until they edit the post again.

Comment: Ah, so you want to prevent them from doing that in the first place? What function is used to submit form data to the database, then?

Comment: Yeah thats correct. Otherwise they can submit posts with huge `h1`s and other annoying stuff. It is building an array to save it as a `post` so it can then be saved within the database. I have tried wrapping the `POST` variable in `strip_tags` before it gets saved... Although there was still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is to hook to a filter that is ran before updating the post in the database. You can then strip the tags or do any other interactions with the post's content and other properties.

Here's an example code that removes any tags before the post is saved:

```
function my_remove_content_html( $data ){
    $data['post_content'] = strip_tags( $data['post_content'] );

    return $data;
}
```

You can enable HTML tags just for admins like so:

```
function my_remove_content_html( $data ){
    if ( ! is_super_admin() ) {
        $data['post_content'] = strip_tags( $data['post_content'] );
    }

    return $data;
}
```

You can also restrict the stripping of the tags to a specific post type like so:

```
function my_remove_content_html( $data ){
    if ( 'post' == $data['post_type'] ) {
        $data['post_content'] = strip_tags( $data['post_content'] );
    }

    return $data;
}
```